# Iframe Resizer - works on some pages but not others

Tags: iframe-resizer

I've tried all the troubleshooting suggestions, and I've got **iFrameResizer** working on other sites without any issues, but it's snagging on this one and I can't fathom out why. Weirdly, it works on the details page, but not on the listing page. Logging returns the

> "hasn't responded in 5 seconds" message.

I've also tried all the various triggers ('max' etc.) none of them make a difference.

Example page where it doesn't work:
http://www.homesinfocus.co.uk/properties-to-let/

But on the details page, it does work:
http://www.homesinfocus.co.uk/property-details-let/?ID=790&LB=Let

I've made sure all the iFrames have unique IDs, and the listing page works okay for other sites, just can't see where the issue is with this one.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your not working page just worked fine for me in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: With no white space under the list items? It's still not working for me. Code inspector shows the element style is getting the "overflow: hidden" part added, but not the height attribute. It works everywhere else for me, just not on this particular site.

Answer (score 1):

David, thanks for your help. CheckOrigin seems to have fixed it.

Seems to work fine with the following:

```
<script>    
$(window).on('load', function (e) {
   $('iframe').iFrameResize({checkOrigin:false});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for that, is that the iframe hasn't loaded it's js file.

Also check that your using the very latest version, as the error message gives a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked that though. The iFrames share the same header file. The resizer js file is loading okay, and working, on the details page - just not on the listing page.

Comment: `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.homesinfocus.co.uk') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.propertywindow.com').` Does the remote site do a redirect. You need to unsure `www.propertywindow.com` is listed as an allowed origin. See the docs on how to set this.

Comment: Thanks David. I had more success yesterday after wrapping the trigger code in an on load event. I think the problem with this particular site may be that there aren't many properties on it so the iFrame renders quite quickly. The other sites, where it's working without any problems, have full pages (10 properties per page) so the iFrame takes longer to render, which seems to help the scripts communicate.